# Turning off Gmail Chat

Tags: gmail, google-talk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove the Chat box from the left pane on gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/102/remove-the-chat-box-from-the-left-pane-on-gmail)

Can I completely prevent the download and usage of 'Chat' in Gmail?

When you turn off the chat in Gmail by clicking the given link, you are logged of the chat. But the files/scripts required for running the chat are downloaded anyways. Like Buzz, you can completely turn it off. What I want is Gmail Labs like functionality, where you can completely turnoff the extension and it won't get downloaded again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the answers to [this previous question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/102/remove-the-chat-box-from-the-left-pane-on-gmail) about the same thing?

If you want to block certain scripts then AdBlock should do the trick - you can specify the path to the specific scripts, or you can use wild cards to block a range (obviously only works in the same browsers that AdBlock supports).